# Webpack code splitting in NPM package. Error: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk failed

Tags: npm, webpack, code-splitting

I am trying to make NPM package (from this code https://github.com/paveli/react-payment-icons-inline).

In this package I use [code splitting with import() syntax](https://github.com/paveli/react-payment-icons-inline/blob/7d5c0d9be6268f2256696c518092dfe1356eb928/src/PaymentIcon.jsx#L147).

I’ve tested it in local project (not as a package) and everything worked fine.

Then published to NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-payment-icons-inline) and tried to use it as a dependency in the app created with create-react-app (code: https://github.com/paveli/react-payment-icons-inline-test).

When I run the app I receive an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 56 failed.
(missing: http://localhost:3000/56.57c19721fd329317ea9e.js)
    at index.js:494
```

I assume this error is connected to webpack. App can’t access chunks from NPM package. Can anyone please suggest a way to fix it?

Comment: I know this is old, but shouldn't your chunk being loaded from something like 'http://localhost:3000/static/js/56.57c19721fd329317ea9e.js' or similar? Are your js files all in the same folder with the html page?

Comment: sounds like you have a problem like this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7417

Answer (score 0):

You need to have multiple entries in Webpack which will create multiple js bundles.
Then you import specific bundles in your main project with React.Lazy